# I have accidentally broken /bin/bash

Tags: linux, bash

I just started using Linux. I'm using Ubuntu and I think I made a very grave mistake. I made a script and by some stupid sense I decided to move it to my `/bin` folder, but I accidentally typed

```
mv /home/kenny/script /bin/bash
```

Now I have lost my bash and don't know what to do. Every time I run bash I get a "too many symbolic links" error.

What can I do to restore my /bin/bash?

Comment: Just in passing - the usual place to put your own programs (including scripts) is in `/usr/local/bin`.  I find that putting my own scripts there helps me keep track of what's mine and what belongs to packages.  (and I give write permission to my `admin` group - who can't write to `/bin` or `/usr/bin`...)

Answer (score 2):

You can try running `/bin/sh` instead.

After that, reinstall bash:

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall /bin/bash
```

This should fix your error.

Comment: sh isn't working...it says sh isn't installed. So I installed it but I got a dpkg-preconfigure error

Answer (score 1):

The main shell used by the ubuntu system itself is `/bin/dash`.

So try to run that. It has no features for interactive use like completion,
but it's a full shell in terms of basic shell features.

You already commented that `/bin/sh` is missing, which is a symbolic link to `/bin/dash`.
Either the link, or the `dash` binary is missing.

But I would expect that Ubuntu can not do much without `dash`, and it seems to be still up - so we can hope hope `/bin/dash` is there.
Maybe some scripts in of the system are made to run with `dash`, but specify to use `sh`, which is now missing.

You could recreate the symbolic link `/bin/sh` pointing to `/bin/dash` by:

```
sudo ln -s -r /bin/dash /bin/sh
```

The system itself does not need `bash` - all scripts that are part of the Ubuntu system should run with the features of `dash`.

Only interactive terminals run bash by default, and it's required by custom scripts when they start with the line `#!/bin/bash`.

Other shells to try:

- `/bin/zsh`
- `/bin/csh`
- `/bin/tcsh`
- `/bin/mksh`
- `/bin/lksh`

Comment: Thank you dash works but now I'm having trouble installing. apt-get install gives error

Comment: Ok - add the error message to the question. You could recreate the link `/bin/sh` by `sudo ln -s -r /bin/dash /bin/sh`.

Comment: @kenny you may need to temporarily create a symbolic link from dash to bash i.e. using a dash shell, `sudo ln -s dash /bin/bash`: this should be enough for the replacement bash package's install scripts to run and thus allow you to re-install the "real" bash. Yes [I have tried it once for fun](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2193544&p=12873003#post12873003).

Comment: @steeldriver Good point, but that command needs to be run in the directory `/bin` to create the link there.

Answer (score 0):

Check if you have bash in `/usr/bin/`.

If so, if it's like on my distro, then `/bin` is a link to `/usr/bin/`; 
so with any hope you only have crashed `/bin/bash` with your mv, and can restore it from `/usr/bin/`

Comment: If he wanted to put _anything_ in /bin, he must have had root access. Hence, the problem isn't using root rights, but rather a simple mistake.

Comment: Its not there in /usr/bin...and I know and lesson learnt, don't go messing with sudo.